# Как программно реализовать tabbar на андроид

Tags: android, java

Всем добрый вечер!
В процессе разработки приложения встала необходимость реализации нижне панели из 4 элементов программно, так чтобы они были на всех окнах! Реализовать нужно в base activity от которой будут на следовать остальные!

Буду рад любой помощи!
Заранее всем большое спасибо!

Comment: @vanyamelikov, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Реализуйте всё остальное Фрагментами.

Comment: Кто сказал что я сформулировал задачу которая требует от вас решения без моего участия? Что я могу добавить, это то что я предполагал реализовать все actionbar tab но их можно только сверху! А если снизу то на ограниченном колве размеров экрана! А я хотел бы как на iOS!

Comment: а не нужно делать как на айось. Это первый признак, что делаете плохой дизайн.

Comment: Это первый признак того что дизайн рисует дизайнер а заверяет его заказчик и поэтому я ничегошеньки не решаю!(

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте почитать про `TabActivity`. Правда оно уже немного деприкатед в 4вёрке видимо, но можно будет понять на что заменять.

Но общая идея такая что вы рисуете в активити произвольный TabHost, ну и программно наполняете его (вкладками). Сами вкладки можете разместить тоже свершено произвольно, хоть по диагонали :-) И в зависимости от выбранной вкладки, в отведённом месте активити будет отображаться другое активити.

подробнее можно почитать тут (http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/140-urok-77-tab-vkladki-tabactivity-activity-kak-soderzhimoe-vkladki) или в официальной документации.

Comment: TabActivity не есть хорошо! И у меня используются фрагменты и view pager а они чет друг с другом хреново! Кстати а как реализовать анимации скрытия tabbar при скроллинге?

Comment: Скрытие? Наверное как с обычным компонентом? А чем Вам TabActivity не нравиться?